# How to monitor hadoop cluster using Ambari on centos 7

Tags: apache, hadoop, centos, cloud, ambari

I have a small hadoop cluster i.e one master and three slave nodes. I have to monitor cluster. I have found that we can use Ambari. CentOS 7 is installed on all machines. Please provide a complete details how I can do that ?. I have found that Ambari can be used for new cluster i.e you have to install new cluster. It does not work with already running cluster?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Ambari does not support CentOS 7, so that's not going to work.

However, Ambari does not perform cluster monitoring on its own. It uses Nagios for the purpose. Nagios is an independent software project that you can setup independently. That said it's kinda painful to do.

Answer (score 0):

ambari-server for Ambari 2.2+ can be installed and works good on CentOS 7.
You have to installed ambari-server on one of the hosts (master node) and can use the webUI `hostname:8080` for installing ambari agents on other hosts. Alternatively, ambari agents can be installed manually on other hosts can can be linked to communicate with the ambari-server.